PowerBI Custom column to retrieve previous value form another column with conditions
My table contains transaction records with end date, this is the "start date" of the next record, need to add a column to get the previous date and reset when the "Order Number" changes
Current data table:
Order Number | Item Number | Operations Sequence Number | End Date
-------------------------------------------------------------------
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 265                        | 03/02/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 300                        | 03/02/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 301                        | 03/06/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 310                        | 03/06/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 320                        | 03/10/2023

Expected result to retrieve previous date as starting date for each event
Order Number | Item Number | Operations Sequence Number | End Date   | Start Date
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 265                        | 03/02/2023 | 
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 300                        | 03/02/2023 | 03/02/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 301                        | 03/06/2023 | 03/06/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 310                        | 03/06/2023 | 03/06/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 320                        | 03/10/2023 | 03/10/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 330                        | 03/21/2023 | 03/10/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 335                        | 03/23/2023 | 03/21/2023
1486120      | GM7666-1    | 340                        | 04/04/2023 | 03/23/2023


Please avoid sharing data as pictures.

you can try this to create a new column in PQ
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom", each 
[a=Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type",(x)=>x[ordernumber]=[ordernumber] and x[Operations Sequence Number]<[Operations Sequence Number]),
b=a[End Date],
c=List.Max(b)][c])


or you can use DAX to create a column
Column =
VAR _OSN =
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[ordernumber] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ordernumber] )
                && 'Table'[Operations Sequence Number]
                    < EARLIER ( 'Table'[Operations Sequence Number] )
        ),
        'Table'[Operations Sequence Number]
    )
RETURN
    MAXX (
        FILTER (
            'Table',
            'Table'[ordernumber] = EARLIER ( 'Table'[ordernumber] )
                && 'Table'[Operations Sequence Number] = _OSN
        ),
        'Table'[End Date]
    )



You can create a calculated column where you store the Order Number and the current End Date to later retrieve the max End Date from the previous rows where the "Order Number" matches the current row and the "Operations Sequence Number" is less than the current one.
Start Date = 
VAR CurrentOrderNumber = 'YourTable'[Order Number]
VAR CurrentEndDate = 'YourTable'[End Date]
RETURN 
    CALCULATE(
        MAX('YourTable'[End Date]),
        FILTER(
            'YourTable',
            'YourTable'[Order Number] = CurrentOrderNumber &&
            'YourTable'[Operations Sequence Number] < EARLIER('YourTable'[Operations Sequence Number])
        )
    )


